Difference between 0f and 0 on a Vector2 and Vector3 in Unity
Recenty started following a Unity tutorial and the script for the character controller is like this:
Vector2 inputVector = new Vector2(0, 0);

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
    inputVector.y = +1;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
    inputVector.y = -1;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) {
    inputVector.x = -1;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
    inputVector.x = +1;
}

inputVector = inputVector.normalized;

Vector3 moveDir = new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0f, inputVector.y);
transform.position += moveDir;
Debug.Log(inputVector);

I understand that '0f' is so 0 is registered as a float rather than an integer but why is this needed in the Vector3 and not the Vector2 even though both of them require floats?
Thanks,
RandomCodeEnjoyer

"but why is this needed in the Vector3 and not the Vector2" it isn't :) Both will work with either 0 or 0f.

The constructors for Vector2 and Vector3 look like this:
public Vector2(float x, float y);
public Vector3(float x, float y, float z);

Therefore, it doesn't matter at all how you specify the number: 0 or 0f. The number will still be converted to float.
In which cases is it important to explicitly specify the type?

Automatic deduce of the variable type:

var x = 0f; // x is float


Loss of precision in integer arithmetic:

var i = 1;                          // i is int
var v1 = new Vector2(i / 2,  0);    // v1.x = 0f
var v2 = new Vector2(i / 2f, 0);    // v2.x = 0.5f


The presence of several class constructors that accept arguments of different types (but it's more of a theory, no one does that):

var v1 = new Vec2(0, 0);    // Vec2(int x, int y) is called
var v2 = new Vec2(0, 0f);   // Vec2(float x, float y) is called
var v3 = new Vec2(0f, 0f);  // Vec2(float x, float y) is called

public class Vec2
{
    public Vec2(int x, int y) => Console.WriteLine("Constructor for int");
    public Vec2(float x, float y) => Console.WriteLine("Constructor for float");
}

